# Metasploit cannot detect language pack on Windows 7

Tags: backtrack, exploit

I use Metasploit (I have Backtrack 5 installed on VirtualBox) to attack my Windows 7 64-bit laptop. Every time I use exploit ms08-067-netapi I get this message:

> [*] Started bind handler
>
> [*] Automatically detecting the
>   target...
>
> [*] Fingerprint: Windows 7 Home
>   Premium (Build 7601) - lang:Unknown
>
> [*] We could not detect the language
>   pack, defaulting to English
>
> [-] No matching target
>
> [*] Exploit completed, but no session
>   was created.

I wanted to try to set the target system but Windows 7 is not listed there. Any ideas?

Comment: A) I assume you're trying to use the Greyhat Ethical Hacker Book, and B) Ask on IT Security, they can probably help you.

Comment: @ekaj to be honest I do not remember if I was using this book at that time. What do you mean by 'ask on IT security'? There is no such stackexchange page as far as I know.

Comment: .. itsecurity.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ekaj [Please don't](http://meta.superuser.com/q/4030/48078) drop comments like "Ask on Whatever.SE" without mentioning that the question can be migrated if the OP wants to. As it stands, the question is *still* on-topic here. Cheers! Patryk, you *can* flag your question for migration if you would like to. You could also offer a bounty if you're still interested in an answer, in order to attract attention.